# Smooth switching between multiple divs: blend effect

Tags: jquery, fade

I have a list with four links to switch between four divs which works quite fine. Now I’d like to add a smooth blend effect when switching between the divs. Currently the animation is a bit rough because the new div fades in below the former active one and jumps to the right position when the other div is faded out.

http://jsfiddle.net/z6UH5/

HTML

```
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-1">
      Tab 1
    </div>

    <div id="tab-2">
      Tab 2
    </div>

    <div id="tab-3">
      Tab 3
    </div>

    <div id="tab-4">
      Tab 4
    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tabs div').hide();
  $('#tabs div:first').show();
  $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');

  $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){ 
      $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 

      var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); 

      $('#tabs div').fadeOut();
      $(currentTab).fadeIn();
      return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to leave the fadeIn(), try just adding:

```
#tabs div  { position:absolute;}
#tabs li.active a { pointer-events:none;}
```

here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6UH5/7/)

Comment: With this solution, the divs fade into each other without white pause :)

Comment: I like your proposed solution but if you press the same `<li>` item multiple times, the transparent fade effect still stands the same. So not entirely true webkit.

Comment: true, but usually the active tab is disabled for clicks anyways, though I should have maybe added that the fiddle.. I will!

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what I was looking for. urbz is correct: Is there a way to disable the effect when clicking on the active li or to disable the active link?

Comment: +1 for `pointer-events` property. Haven't seen that being used quite often. And your proposed solution is quite clean and neat. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach, moving the text from the anchor to an isolated div, then fading and showing the contents of the div. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z6UH5/9/).

JS

```
$('.tabholder div').show();
$('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
$('.tabholder').html( $('#tabs ul li a:first').html() );


$('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){ 
  $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  var clickedtab = $(this);

  $('.tabholder').fadeOut( 500, function(){
                          $('.tabholder').html( clickedtab.html() );
                          $('.tabholder').fadeIn();
                                           });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change

```
$('#tabs div').fadeOut();
```

to

```
$('#tabs div').hide();
```

or if it so necessary you can set fixed height of container div and set overflow to hidden:

```
#tabs {
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6UH5/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

`$('#tabs div').fadeOut().delay(300);`

instead of:

`$('#tabs div').fadeOut();`

This fades out existing div, adds some delay and then fades in current div, so that you get the blend effect in a smooth way.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z6UH5/3/)